# How to keep Baloo running but with lower ressource consumption?

Tags: kde, baloo

Good afternoon everybody,

I have a question related to Baloo.
I saw the thread posted on the same forum :

[How to turn off baloo in KDE 4.13?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437635/how-to-turn-off-baloo-in-kde-4-13)

I also face the issue of high ressource consumption mentioned everywhere on that post.
But unlike the question raised there, I would actually like to keep the search functionalities, so still allow baloo to run...

I have noticed that the process baloo_file_extractor is ok in terms of CPU but seems really greedy in terms of I/O.

- CPU < 10%, in top command
- I/O >95%, in iotop command, active 2 seconds out of 3.

The load average of the computer increases (~4.8 in top) as well as the overall CPU usage (>95% according to processor control). It causes my laptop to freeze 1 second every 3 seconds. Suspending (STOP signal) 3 processes :

- baloo_file_extractor
- baloo_file
- akonadi_baloo_indexer

brings the laptop to a smooth running.

Is there anyway to reduce the I/0 demand ?

Cheers

Comment: A similar issue is raised on KDE forum : [baloo high disk usage causing ui freezes, perf issues](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=154&t=120563). A bug was submitted accordingly [KDE 333433](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=333433)

Comment: The Baloo is a new app - the KDE Commit Diegest ( http://commit-digest.org/issues/2014-03-30/ ) has : 'This Week...
 Baloo reduces io usage during initial indexing...' I'm not sure if it is in the KDE SC 4.13.1 but the Kubuntu Updates PPA ( https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ppa ) has the latest KDE . Advanced baloo configuration module: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?65271-Baloo-links

Answer (score 2):

All in all, bug [KDE 333433](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=333433) dealt with treatment of external media mounted on /home.

I had a symbolic link to an external media in /home (maybe a bad practice from me...). 
This external media was excluded from the indexing (KDE System Config -> Search on Desktop).

After this exclusion, the situation seems to be cured : no freeze.
Baloo processes (baloo_file_extractor, baloo_file, akonadi_baloo_indexer and cleaner) run for some time (~1h) still with a rather high CPU (average over time ~40%) but affordable.
The computer is now running fine.