# baloo_file_extractor in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS taking up a lot of memory

Tags: baloo

The `baloo_file_extractor` process in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS takes up a lot of memory. `top` reports 84.3% of my 15.6 GB, - and some 20% (more or less) of the CPU.

I do not even run KDE, - I am in a Gnome session.

I note that there has previously (in 2014) been a problem with `baloo_file_extractor`, see [How to keep Baloo running but with lower ressource consumption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465807/how-to-keep-baloo-running-but-with-lower-ressource-consumption) But I suppose that is fixed. I do not have any external media mounted.

Comment: For now (as I am running Gnome), I have done this dramatic fix: `sudo aptitude remove baloo-kf5`, logout and login, i.e., removing KDE parts.

Answer (score 0):

I removed baloo through Synaptic.  It turned out to be associated with KDE's file manager, which I had tried but found no advantage over using Ubuntu's.  So I removed all of it.

Baloo was using 6 GB of RAM which is ridiculous.  I just installed it a week ago, in late August, 2019, I don't think they fixed it!  And it had a subprocess that was using a lot of resources as well.  Every time I booted up my computer I had to go into process manager and terminal and kill them or my computer would crawl.

I'm not even going to try to fix something like that, that's for KDE/ Kubuntu, if they cared, which they must not.  It seems like none of their utilities work properly without creating far more problems than they're worth.  I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.   I might install the Kubuntu desktop only in time, but I'm leaving its utilities alone!