# How do I stop and remove KDE Baloo that is broken and filling up my syslog file?

Tags: kde, 19.10, syslog, baloo

KDE baloo has recently caused `rsyslog` to start logging many errors.

### Part of 'Syslog'

```
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PositionDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PostingDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PositionDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PostingDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PositionDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PostingDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PostingDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PositionDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PostingDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PositionDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar  3 15:01:53 harry-S340 baloo_file.desktop[2982]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PostingDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
```

It caused my `/var/log/syslog` to grow exponentially, it filled the disk once already, I've since disabled `rsyslog` to stop this from destroying my SSD and making Ubuntu unusable but I don't know what Baloo is or how to stop and uninstall it. When i fist noticed this `/var/log/syslog` had grown to 66GB causing my disk to be FULL. I was able to delete it and log back in and disable `rsyslog` through recovery mode. Running `rsyslog` for one second caused it to go up to `75MB`.

### 'Neofetch --off' result

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 
Host: 81NC Lenovo IdeaPad S340-15API 
Kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic 
Uptime: 11 mins 
Packages: 3040 (dpkg), 38 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.3 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.100GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Picasso 
Memory: 2756MiB / 5945MiB
```

I don't want to uninstall the whole of KDE straight away but if that is the only way to get rid of this broken program then I happily will.

### Other commands

```sh
harry@harry-S340:~$ whereis baloo
baloo:
```

```sh
harry@harry-S340:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove baloo
[sudo] password for harry: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'baloo' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
```

```sh
harry@harry-S340:~$ whereis baloo_file
baloo_file: /usr/bin/baloo_file
```

```sh
harry@harry-S340:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove baloo_file
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package baloo_file
```

```sh
harry@harry-S340:~$ sudo systemctl status baloo_file
Unit baloo_file.service could not be found.
```

Pressing tab to see all the commands that have baloo in them:

```
harry@harry-S340:~$ baloo
balooctl                           baloo_filemetadata_temp_extractor
baloo_file                         baloosearch
baloo_file_extractor               balooshow
```

these all don't have any manuals

```
harry@harry-S340:~$ man baloo
No manual entry for baloo
harry@harry-S340:~$ man baloo_file
No manual entry for baloo_file
harry@harry-S340:~$ man balooctl
No manual entry for balooctl
harry@harry-S340:~$ man baloosearch
No manual entry for baloosearch
harry@harry-S340:~$ man balooshow
No manual entry for balooshow
harry@harry-S340:~$ man baloo_filemetadata_temp_extractor
No manual entry for baloo_filemetadata_temp_extractor
harry@harry-S340:~$ man baloo_file_extractor
No manual entry for baloo_file_extractor
```

### Desktop file mentioned in `syslog`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=baloo_file
X-KDE-StartupNotify=false
X-KDE-autostart-condition=baloofilerc:Basic Settings:Indexing-Enabled:true
X-KDE-autostart-phase=0
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
OnlyShowIn=KDE;GNOME;Unity;XFCE
NoDisplay=true
```

### Requests

#### Balooctl status

```bsh
harry@harry-S340:~$ balooctl status
Baloo File Indexer is running
Indexer state: Indexing file content
Total files indexed: 109,311
Files waiting for content indexing: 3
Files failed to index: 4
Current size of index is 507.65 MiB
```

```bsh
harry@harry-S340:~$ sudo balooctl disable
[sudo] password for harry: 
Disabling and stopping the File Indexer
```

this stopped `rsyslog` filling up `/var/log/syslog`.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: What does `balooctl status` show?

Comment: Did `balooctl status` and updated question with result. index 4 failed is this causing this.

Comment: I don't see the output of exactly `balooctl status`.

Comment: ```Baloo File Indexer is running      
Indexer state: Indexing file content        
Total files indexed: 109,311    
Files waiting for content indexing: 3     
Files failed to index: 4    
Current size of index is 507.65 MiB```

Comment: Then run `balooctl disable`.

Comment: By the way you need to resolve "0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade." as well.

Comment: result ```harry@harry-S340:~$ sudo balooctl disable      
[sudo] password for harry:      
Disabling and stopping the File Indexer```

Comment: Don't use `sudo` unless it's explicitly required. It shouldn't be needed in this case.

Comment: thought it might be needed as it is like `systemctl`, anyway is `baloo` required by KDE Plasma or can it be removed and what is its package name?

Comment: Baloo isn't a typical package that can be uninstalled with `sudo apt purge ...`. To see packages involving `baloo`, run `apt list --installed | grep -i baloo`. But now baloo is turned off permanently on your system and there's no need to "remove" it.

Comment: This is what I did to remove baloo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is how I removed baloo

```
balooctl disable                  # stops the service
sudo apt install -s baloo         # where to find baloo
sudo apt remove --purge libkf5balooengine5
rm -rf .local/share/baloo/        # removes the index files; they can be several GB
```

There are some related answers at [Baloo creates 64GB index, takes half my memory and 25% CPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154499/baloo-creates-64gb-index-takes-half-my-memory-and-25-cpu)

Comment: `sudo apt remove --purge libkf5balooengine5` isn't an option for me, because it removes a lot of useful software (`dolphin`, `gwenview`, `kinfocenter`, `plasma-desktop`/`plasma-workspace`, `sddm-theme-breeze`), but `balooctl disable` really helped.

Answer (score 7):

For me, it just helped to disable content indexing like this:

```
balooctl config set contentIndexing no
```

This way, baloo should quickly make the index just for file names, so you can still search for file names in Dolphin.

Comment: Is this permanent? Does it persist a reboot?

Comment: From my experience, yes.

Answer (score 4):

I need to keep baloo, this corrected the syslog debugging issue, so I ran the following with success:

```
balooctl disable && balooctl purge && balooctl enable
```

Checking Status with `balooctl status` I get:

```
Baloo File Indexer is running
Indexer state: Idle
Total files indexed: 1,287
Files waiting for content indexing: 0
Files failed to index: 0
Current size of index is 16.04 MiB
```

Everything is now fine, disabling, purging, re-enabling the service keeps monitoring syslog in case

Comment: `baloo` was reading and writing a ton of data and I needed to keep it since it would break with my desktop environment. This stopped baloo from reading and writing so much, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This removed everything baloo without removing dolphin, plasma, kde. I was having screen lockups and the baloo_file indexer taking 112% cpu--I lost work rebooting because I could not even move into a terminal window and kill baloo_file. I am going to make this a cron script in case upgrades re-install baloo. You'd think the maintainer would renice baloo_file to lowest priority! That would not be great. I'm in Ubuntu 20.10 desktop.

```
balooctl disable 

for baloo in `dpkg --list 'baloo-kf5*' 'libkf5baloo5*' 'libkf5balooengine5*' 'libkf5baloowidgets-bin*' 'libkf5baloowidgets-data*' 'libkf5baloowidgets5*' | sed -n -E '/^ii/s/^ii[\t ]+([^\t :]+).*/\1/p'`
 do echo $baloo
 sudo snap remove $baloo
 sudo dpkg --ignore-depends=$baloo --purge $baloo
done

rm -rf .local/share/baloo/

sudo updatedb ; ls `locate baloo`
```