# Is it safe to disable baloo_file_extractor in KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: 18.04, baloo

Today after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, I found `baloo_file_extractor` consuming too much RAM and causing my laptop to slow down. I can temporarily fix this by running `balooctl disable`. I did a little googling and found out that it related to KDE which is weird I am using GNOME.

So is it safe to disable it or remove it altogether?  If not, is there a way to make it not consume too much RAM?

Comment: Same problem. In my case it was installed when I tried digikam + piki-plugins. I purged both with apt + autoremove but a hell of libraries remained, including dolphin, konqueror and baloo…

Comment: It seems the problem was konqueror, automatically installed by apt because it is  recommended by piki-plugins (and recommended packages are usually not removed by apt…). Had to manually remove it, and then autoremove took care of libkf5baloo* and many others. [I am still tracking other recommended libraries not removed by apt, such as libkf5configcore5…]. Use an AppImage! :(

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's safe to use `balooctl disable`.

You need to be careful while installing software. Pay attention to what's being installed and to what's being pulled in by way of dependencies. For example, you *may* have installed `dolphin`, the file manager. That would pull in `libkf5baloo5` and `libkf5baloowidgets5` among other things. `gwenview`, an image viewer, would pull in `libkf5baloo5`.

If you're interested in chasing things down, run `apt rdepends libkf5baloo5` and `apt rdepends libkf5baloowidgets5` and examine the output for software packages you may have on your system.

Under normal circumstances in Kubuntu 18.04, which includes `baloo` by default, use of resources is minimal after the initial indexing process. RAM and CPU usage are not normally a concern. But there **are** reports of `baloo` running amok even on pure Kubuntu! I use it without problems for indexing both filenames and file contents.

Comment: so after a week, it doesn't show any problem. thanks, you are right.

Comment: I also noticed slowing down of my Linux mint with cinnamon DE. Disk IO appears high and even saving code in vim becomes sluggish. Thanks for pointing out `dolphin`, I did install that and the `baloo_file_extractor` was the thing that got installed and was doing something in the background that slows down the system.

Comment: the only thing that drive me nuts is why these system hogging things dont come by design with ionice "best effort"? and from time to time we lose a lot of time having to find a way to deal with some random weirdness :(. I still love Linux tho.

Answer (score 3):

i am using Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome, maybe it helps for others.

i had this 100% cpu core problem with baloo_file and baloo_file_extractor processes. i don't know deeply but i saw that it was related with KDE environment.

and i also installed dolphin for some reason before. so first i removed it from the system using "stacer" app. but problem has not gone. then i remove and purge dependencies with double check :) and problem solved!

```
sudo apt-get autoremove dolphin
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge dolphin
```

it is a bit disappointment that baloo core 100% usage since i really like KDE.
after some observation i saw that baloo uses each core with some scheduling algorithm. at some certain time it uses let say core 1 with 100% and then after a couple of minutes goes to other core. maybe it is designed to maintainability but 100% is not acceptable. because it is over heated some certain part of cpu and fans getting started.