# locate vs. baloo

Tags: disk-usage, dolphin, locate, baloo

I have Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

I was used to `locate` as an indexed search tool. Combined with `grep` (and sometimes `find`) it is a swiss-army knife for file searching and inspecting.

I have yesterday noticed that something was eating up my little spare space available.
Today I concluded `~/.local/share/baloo/index` is the culprit.

The respective spaces taken are

```
/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db    47M
~/.local/share/baloo/index    7,5G
```

**Is such a large difference normal?**
**What additional information does `baloo` carry, to use such a large space?**
**Can `baloo` be configured in a way that it uses a space similar to `mlocate.db` (even at the expense of some indexed information)?**

PS 1: I didn't know about `baloo` until today.

PS 2: I have `apt-get install`ed `dolphin` a couple of days ago, and I guess `baloo` came along.

PS 3: I have used `dolphin` since ancient times as well, in other systems, and I never noticed anything strange.
I wouldn't know if in those other cases `baloo` was also installed but it lead to no issues, or if it was not installed at all.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1154650/248158

Comment: @DKBose - I had read it prior to posting.

Comment: How to disable: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068788/is-it-safe-to-disable-baloo-file-extractor

Comment: @CiroSantilli冠状病毒审查六四事件法轮功 - How to configure: Please see added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be set in the configuration file `~/.config/baloofilerc` ([official documentation](https://community.kde.org/Baloo/Configuration)).

In particular, the setting that controls the amount of information indexed is [the block](https://community.kde.org/Baloo/Configuration#Only_index_Files_Names)

```
[General]
only basic indexing=true
```

This will trigger Baloo to only index the filenames.
I did not try yet indexing this way and checking the used space.

PS: On a first reading, I did not find what other information is indexed if not set to "only filenames".

PS2: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1154650/248158) is a helpful reading.