# what's baloo_file_extractor's process?

Tags: 20.04, process, baloo

The other day when I started my computer, it went lagging;
today I started it and it seems to be gone but when I went through the task manager, I saw that `baloo_file_extractor` takes about 50% of CPU, it goes down after a few minutes but it still takes about 6GB of RAM.

I saw on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267830/what-does-baloo-file-extractor-do) that it is related to KDE but I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (most recent stable version) which uses gnome and not KDE.
I used to have installed dolphin which I tested twice but I uninstalled it and rebooted.

Can I kill it or is there any risks, how to permanently delete it ?