# Release upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 - takes too long (almost 6 hrs and still in progress), any pointers?

Tags: 18.04, apt, 20.04, upgrade, update-manager

Folks,

I started a release upgrade via the software updater from 18.04 to 20.04. It went through the *Preparing to upgrade → Setting new software channels → Getting new packages* fine. And then its been in 'installing the upgrades' for nearly 5 hours now. Progress bar at less than 10% of its width, its the same all these hours. However in the terminal I can see that packages are indeed being installed. I keep getting 'Preparing to unpack...' , 'unpacking...', '(Reading database...)' etc... over and over with different packages, but I am surprised that it is taking this long and the progress bar shows just 10%...

A screenshot of the dist upgrade window:

[image: Screenshot]

Does this usually take this long?
Any pointers/logs to look for that might indicate where the problem is?
Is there a way to stop the upgrade?

When I do a top I see 'baloo_file_extr' taking most of the cpu... but I suppose this is ok?

Thanks!

Comment: Upgrades can take a *loooooooooooong* time, I had my last two QA-test *release-upgrade* take an average of ~16 hours last time I did it (*I've thankfully not done any in recent releases!*), depending on your bandwidth speeds, CPU/disk speeds, number of packages etc...  If it's a desktop system, an *upgrade via re-install* is far faster (~15 mins for the same result on the same hardware) is what I actually did when I needed to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04..  but yes it can takes a long (*most users find it way less than what I experienced*)

Comment: Yes, I understand that upgrades can take a long time. I had upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 just a couple of days back. It took quite a while. What worries me is that in this one... after all this time the progress bar has barely moved. I've attached a screenshot, take a look. If I extrapolate that, I suppose this upgrade will take a couple of days! That doesn't seem right... hence the question.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1267830/243321

Answer (score 0):

Baloo indeed turned out to be the problem.
I tried disabling it with balooctl but that complained about the absence of a specific version of some library. I assume this is because a release upgrade is in progress.

So I had to explicitly kill the process. Once I did that, the upgrade started progressing much quicker….. about 60% done in 2 hours..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thank you for contributing. Please take the [tour]. When posting, please never add "Greetings", "G'day Ubuntu Users", "Folks", "I have a problem" at the start of your post -- it is never necessary.   Similarly, please never use a sign-off, "thanks", "any suggestions appreciated ", "please help" etc.